# Drupal redirect from installation subdirectory without creating a loop

Tags: apache, .htaccess, drupal, mod-rewrite

I am working on a Drupal site that has hard coded links in lots of the content (I didn't create the site). Unfortunately that means the site has to be in a subdirectory such as "www.example.com/drupal" or the links will break. I have sucessfully redirected the site root to the subdirectory and hid it using the following code in the site root htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (.*) drupal/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\..+$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

However if I go to www.example.com/drupal the subdirectory still shows up.This means that www.example.com and www.example.com/drupal have the same content which is bad for SEO. Is there some way to make /drupal redirect to root without causing a loop? I have tried just about every posted in other threads and none of them work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do the redirect before rewriting the URL. You also need to check that you're actually rewriting to a legitimate resource.

1. swap the rules around, the redirect should happen first
2. Add a check to the drupal rule

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\..+$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/drupal
RewriteRule (.*) drupal/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```